# clickable grid view row asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want asp.net gridview with its rows clickable.

i want to call a function when that row is clicked based on row index.

i tried to use RowDataBound event but it did not worked or me

i used the following code

```
protected void PeopleGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";

            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.PeopleGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }
```

where am i going wrong?

i dont want to redirect to any other page.
i want to fill the values in text box on the same page

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function in javascript and call it from mouse event of row.

**Javacript**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function setStyle(obj)
    {
       obj.style.cursor='hand';
       obj.style.textDecoration='underline';
    }

    function resetStyle(obj)
    {
       this.style.textDecoration='none'; 
    }
</script>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void PeopleGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "setStyle(this);";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "resetStyle(this);";

        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.PeopleGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function call(id) {
            alert(id);
            // Do whatever
        }
    </script>

<asp:GridView ID="gvParent" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true"
            PagerSettings-Mode="NextPrevious" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvParent_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind

```
protected void gvParent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string ID = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("HdnID")).Value;

            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";

            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "call(" + ID + ");";
        }
}
```