# vb.net <asp:gridview row open new page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

first of all, i'm very new in asp.net, second, sorry for my english,

I have this .asp code written in vb.net, and I manage to display the gridview's  data. I've also added below lines of code to make the entire row clickable.

```
Private Sub AutoPopulateGridView_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles AutoPopulateGridView.RowCreated
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.color='#47B6D2';"
        e.Row.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';this.style.color='black';"
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to view details"         
    End If
End Sub
```

what I want to do is, when user clicked on each row(s), I'll open a new page loaded with new data that passed by that row the user clicked. and I'm stuck here.

Comment: I think here is your desire answer. [clickable gridview row in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008952/clickable-grid-view-row-asp-net)

Comment: I've try this, but it's gave me error of _Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation. _

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of what you want to do can be done with GridView Templates on your ASPx page.

Instead of letting the GridView define the columns itself, define them with Templates where you can add controls within the grid view.
When you bind your data to the grid view, the controls in each column get bound to your data set automagically. Below, you can see there is a Hyperlink column that uses the Data Table column `my_value_database_column` this value gets passed to the new page on the GET or querystring. (Passing values this way is an HTTP GET).

```
<asp:GridView ID="AutoPopulateGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My Linked Column">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" href='MyNextPage.aspx?valueToPass=<%#Eval("my_value_database_column").ToString()%>'><%# Eval("column_name_with_text").ToString()%></asp:HyperLink>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="boring column" ItemStyle-CssClass="myHoverClass">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <%# Eval("other_datatable_column_name").ToString()%>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

To get the value passed on your next page, in the codebehind (.cs file) retrieve the value from the querystring:

```
public partial class MyNextPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //first page hit
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Write("THE VALUE PASSED WAS '" + Request.QueryString["valueToPass"] + "'");
        }

    }
}
```

ALso, the styles can be added directly to the gridview template in the ASPx page as well, using css and the psudo-class :hover

```
<style type="text/css">
        .myHoverClass {
            text-decoration:none;
            color:black;
        }

        .myHoverClass:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #47B6D2;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: how can I pass the value to another page then?

Comment: Pass Values on the Querystring of the URL.  so for your hyperlink, it would end in a ? then the value would come after:  http://example.com/mynewpage.asp?valueToPass=xxxx, and in the codebehind on the Recieving page, read var myValue = Request.QueryString("valueToPass");

Comment: I'm sorry but don't get it, could u explain in code, or maybe sample websites so I can refer to,thanks

Comment: HI user8129468,  I edited my original response to give you a more complete example.  Hope this helps.  Look closely at the changes to the GridView Template column!  CodeBehind for new page is in C#, should be easy to translate to VB if you really want, but I'd suggest switching to C#  while it is still early.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is little bit different than yours. But you can get idea from here

Here the list of data are showed in table format and editable link also added here so that you will get to know how to pass data(actually item id) using a tag in html.

Here is the code .............

```html
<body>
    <%
    dim query
    Dim objConn, objRS, sqlString
    set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("hospital.mdb")    
    set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sqlString ="select * from Test"
    objRS.Open sqlString, objConn
   
%>
            <table class="table table-border table-hover table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <th>Test Name</th>
                    <th>Test Type</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th></th>
                </thead>
                <% Do Until objRs.EOF = True%>

                <tr id="<%=objRS("iD")%>">
                    <td>
                        <%Response.Write(objRS("TestName"))%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%Response.Write(objRS("Type"))%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%Response.Write(objRS("UnitPrice"))%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%Response.Write(objRS("AddingDate"))%>
                    </td>

                    <td> <a href='editTest.asp?Id=<%=objRS("Id")%>'>Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <%
       objRS.MoveNext
                loop
                objRS.Close
                 objConn.Close
   
   %>
            </table>
</body>
```